# Application need to be updated

Tags: swift, xcode

i have an issue with export IPA to the testers , i upload the app for install on fly by some website but when install the app they appear on the app this icon next to the app [image]

and get messages this app need to be updated by developer to work on this version of iOS with two option keep or delete the app

please if anyone can solve this issue

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Think i got it , because my Xcode higher iOS target 14.5 and my iPhone is 14.7 , it need from me to update the Xcode